# After setting up a second Python environment in Anaconda, importing basic packages fails with [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, anaconda, package, environment

I wanted to have a second environment with Python 3.6 and Tensorflow-GPU v1.15 (my other environment is Python 3.7/TF2.0). I created the environment using the Anaconda prompt and installed packages there. When I try to import pandas or numpy in Jupyter Notebook, it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    346 
    347         if handle is None:
--> 348             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    349         else:
    350             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have retried several time to uninstall/ reinstall the environment with no success. A [github post](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27693) to somebody else's problem suggested to make sure the PATH is clean but I am not sure what it means. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you share how you created the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by deleting the content of: C:\Users[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python